# ObjectOutputStream not sending data (server stuck at socket.accept())

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to send an object over a connection using Java. This is my client side code. The server receives the data the first time, but the second time is stuck at socket.accept(). Am i doing something wrong here? Thank you!

```
  public class Client 
        {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                try 
                {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 40003);
                    ClientObject c = new ClientObject(socket);
                    c.init();

                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        class ClientObject
        {
            Socket socket;

            public ClientObject(Socket socket) 
            {
                this.socket = socket;
            }
            public void init()
            {
                try
                {

                    // computation
                    SendObject so = new SendObject(toSend1, toSend2, rand, username.length());

                    // send all of this
                    OutputStream o = socket.getOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(o);
                    oos.writeObject(so);
                    o.flush();

                    InputStream i = socket.getInputStream();
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(i);

                    // works, data received from the server
                    so = (SendObject)ois.readObject();

                    // further computation
                    so = new SendObject(null, digest, rand + 1, -1);
                    oos.reset();
                    oos.writeObject(so);
                    // doesn't work :(
                    o.flush();

                    }
                    }
```

Comment: You sure it's the client end that is not working?

Comment: The server side is stuck at the `accept()` method. I inferred that the client is not sending any data. Can there be an issue in the server side? I am using threads..

Comment: Years ago I was trying to do the same sort of thing you are doing, and I ran into similar problems with the Object Streams... If possible, I'd recommend using JSON for serialization, rather than java object serialization.

Comment: Will give it a go, because this is frustrating. Can you give me a good link to start? A library, perhaps? Cheers

Comment: How can the server be stuck at accept if it has already successfully received and sent back a SendObject? The connection has been accepted for a long time. Show the server code.

Comment: @JBNizet - yeah, that's what I thought - doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Flush the ObjectOutputStream instead of the underlying OutputStream.
2. The client it's using the same stream and thus the same connection to write to the server, hence the server should not expect a second `accept` but rather keep reading the stream of the same connection. You can of course also set up a new connect (`Socket`) and send the second object over that socket. Then the server should `accept` another socket.

Comment: Embarrassing misunderstanding of how `socket` works in Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks for me, that the server has successfully accepted the connection, otherwise you would not be able to send and receive. Look at your server code the problem may be that you close() the socket connection after the server has received from the client. Pleas provide your server code to have a look at.